# SFML 2.4.2 doesn't draw in VS 2017 Community

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, sfml

I got some stupid problem I can't find a solution to. I'm using visual studio 2017 community and I want to create a window with a black background and a blue circle in it. I'm using c++ and SFML 2.4.2. At the moment it just shows a white empty window.

```
//Main Function
int main() {

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 800), "Window Name");    

    sf::CircleShape creature;
    creature.setRadius(50);
    creature.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
    creature.setPosition(400, 400);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.clear();
        window.draw(creature);
        cout << "Creature draws";
        window.display();
    }    
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

There's no error shown anywhere and I checked several times, that I included SFML properly. Sorry for asking such a question, but I would be glad for help.

Comment: So what happens? Just a black window? No window? Do you see the console output?

Comment: It just shows a white window. The console just shows the text "Creature draws" over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.display()
```

This should be inside the while loop otherwise sfml will not display anything until you close the window.

Comment: I put it into the while loop, there ist still a white window where SFML should draw something. I tested with cout, that the program reaches all positions.

Comment: could you try passing in the colour black to your clear function and tell me what the window does?

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the whole project again and set everything up again the same way. This didn't help either. So I followed another tutorial, which showed me how to install SFML directly into the project and it seems to work just fine now. Thank you for your time and efford!